# magento 2: type differences for scopeConfig and _logger in AbstractHelper class

Tags: magento2, helper, psr-logger

This is probably a very stupid question but I'll ask anyway since I don't know the answer.

This is an example of a custom module helper class that extends magento helper class:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $encryptor;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        EncryptorInterface $encryptor
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->encryptor = $encryptor;
    }

    public function isEnabled($scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag('section/group/field', $scope);
    }
}
```

You can see that I have not explicitly set scopeConfig anywhere, it comes directly form magento default class:

```
namespace Magento\Framework\App\Helper;
abstract class AbstractHelper
{
 /**
  * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
  */
 protected $scopeConfig;
 public function __construct(Context $context)
 {
     $this->scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();     
 }
 ...
}
```

This is enough to work: in my custom class I call $this->scopeConfig and I get what I need (eg: the bool field configuration). The default class has also a logger that looks similar to scopeConfig:

```
protected $_logger;
protected $scopeConfig;

public function __construct(Context $context)
{
    $this->_logger = $context->getLogger();
    $this->scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
}
```

so I thought I could use it the same way. However, this->_logger->info($msg) in my class doesn't work. It's not logging anything:

```
public function isEnabled($scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT)
{
   return $this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag('section/group/field', $scope); // this works
}

public function log($msg = "test")
{
   $this->_logger($msg); // this doesn't work
}
```

Of course, if I inject the loggerInterface directly in my custom class, then everything works fine. But I was wondering why scopeConfig works and _logger doesn't, what's the difference?

Comment: Could it be because you are not returning anything in your log function?

Comment: Hi @Gagan, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately nothing changes if I add a return